# What is the largest number of people that can attend a meeting at one time?

Tags: algorithms

From a given list of ranges, what is the fastest algorithm to find the largest number of ranges that overlap at a single point (or range).

For example, given a list of times a group of people are free in a given day (assuming only one range each i.e. 09:00 - 10:00), what is the largest number of people that can attend a meeting at once.

In this example, if Alice is free 09:00-10:00, Becky 09:30-10:30, and Charlie 12:00-13:00, the best result is two people, (meeting between 09:30-10:00).

I'm almost positive this is a well know problem, I just cant figure out the name to google it!

Comment: Internet citizens of the future: I needed this for an algorithm to find the optimal angle at which a shape rotated about a vertex covers the most points in a set of distributed points. FIrst step being to find the entry and exit angles as the shape is swept round the vertex (these becoming the ranges in the above sections) ie point A intersects the shape as it sweeps by at angles pi -> 2 x pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are realy just singkle ranges per person, the following works in $O(n\log n)$:

For each range $[t_0,t_1]$, insert the pairs $(t_0,+1)$ and $(t_1,-1)$ into a list. Sort this list lexicographically, i.e., according to
$$ (a,b)<(c,d):\iff a<c\lor (a=c\land b<d)$$
Run through the sorted list and accumulate the second component, noting maxima, that is:

1. Set $M\leftarrow0$ (maximum so far), $C\leftarrow 0$ (current available)
2. For each entry $(t,s)$ in sorted order: Set $C\leftarrow C+s$. If $C>M$ set $M\leftarrow C$
3. Output $M$